# Jmeter- XPath Extractor Xpathquery(To parse the vlaue in get request)

Tags: xpath, jmeter, xpathquery

I need to get the value of **xpdi** results from one Get Request. Can anyone please help how to use XPATHQuery in Xpath extractor.(Below is the response)

```
<html>
<head id="ctl00_Head1">
<script type="text/javascript">window.NREUM||(NREUM={});NREUM.info = {"bcon":"bam.nr-data.net","atts":""}
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">(window.NREUM||(NREUM={})).loader_config={xpdi:"UQQBVFJWGwEGVlFRBAgB"};
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you not to use xpath extractor.

Always go with Regular Expression Extractor. XPath extractors take more time and memory & affect the performance of your test plan. Check the comparison [here](http://www.testautomationguru.com/jmeter-response-data-extractors-comparison/).

If you go with Regular Expression Extractor,

Regular Expression would be `xpdi:"(.*?)"`

[image]

You can access the value by using `${xpdi}`

Comment: Hi Vins, if the value needs to be added in Path how would i go about it.  I have a Path: /MSI.aspx?stuf=HdarajiJkllll  . But the Value HdarajiJKllll comes from Previous response Header of Post. I tried using             Regular Expression - MSI.aspx\?stuff=(\w) . And in the path specifying it as ${MSI}. But it doesnot work. Any thoughts?

Comment: @Jack, what is the value of MSI?

Comment: MSI is value of of alphanumerals.

Comment: @Jack, when you say it does not work - what does it mean? 'doesnot work' is very generic..provide more info. what is the value of MSI when it does not work

Comment: The value gets populated a MSI instead of picking up actual alphanumerals.